# What is the meaning of const keyword ?

Tags: c, pointers

What does it mean that a constant is protecting a variable that have 
been passed to a function via pointer?

For example :

```
int f ( const int vec[]);
```

The following command is not legal:

```
vec[i] = exp;
```

Comment: Please change your title.

Comment: const here means that you're not allowed to modify what vec points to, it means just that. vec is meant to be read only

Comment: What is your C book, preferably K&R, "The C Programming Language", 2nd ed., telling you?

Answer (score 4):

`const` protects its left side, unless there is nothing to its left, then and only then it protects its right side. In this case, it protects the values contained in `vec`.

These examples should help you understand this:

A **pointer to a const variable**:

```
int vec[] = {1,2,3};
int const *ptr = vec;
ptr[1] = SOMETHING; //ERROR :(
```

A **const pointer to a variable**:

```
int vec[] = {1,2,3};
int* const ptr = vec;
ptr[1] = SOMETHING; //OK :)
ptr = NULL;         //ERROR :(
```

These images should help you better understand this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

const is a qualifier being enforced by the compiler.  What

```
const int vec[];
```

means is that you cannot modify the ints contained in vec.

NOTE: that this does not mean that the memory isn't modifiable.  People tend to mistake const as a run time guarantee to protect that portion of memory... this is not the case.  This is only something enforced by c compilers, to attempt to protect programmers from doing stupid things.

EDIT: The most obvious use of const, as it pertains to function calls, is when you want to pass things by reference, because they are large and copying them would be expensive.  But you want to guarantee the function won't modify them.

```
int someFunction(const int &notChangeable, int &modifiable);
```

In the above declaration the modifiable integer could be changed by someFunction, and since it was passed by reference, this would be changed for the calling routine as well.  The notChangeable int shouldn't be modified.

Below is an example of some of the nasty things you can do with const and pointers.  Since people were talking about modification of memory, and only being a compile time guarantee, I thought I would demo what this means for you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    const int* intOne = new int(10);
    int* intTwo = new int(20);//Toggle these two lines
    //int* const intTWo = new int(20);//Toggle these two lines

    cout << *intOne << " " << *intTwo << endl;

    intTwo -= sizeof(int); //Let's move our pointer back one integer!
    *intTwo = 50000;//Now let's change that integer

    cout << intOne << " " << intTwo << endl;//INteresting our pointers point to the same memory now

    cout << *intOne << " " << *intTwo << endl;//And we were able to modify *intOne... even though it was const.

}
```

Also note that we have leaked what was pointed to by intTwo, although we know how to get back to it, so this isn't terrible.  And that if you'd like to see the difference between making the pointer constant and the thing it points to constant, you can toggle the two lines I commented.

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
10 20
0x1061009e0 0x1061009e0
50000 50000
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for your response. what are the the privilege of passing a variable as a const pointer to an function

Comment: @user1941008 `const` is to indicate that the function won't change the arguments (and can't). If you try to do this (by mistake), you'll get a compiler error. It's a very good practice to do this. For example: `int strlen(const char[]);`

Comment: It should be noted that `const` is only an assist from the compiler. It is **not** enforced. It is legal to convert a `const int *` to an `int *` and modify the pointed-to object, provided the original object is not defined with `const`. Also, the pointed-to object might be modified by independent means, such as a separate pointer passed in another parameter.

Comment: This is a C question.  Why are you giving an answer with examples in C++?

Comment: The way I use the const modifier is identical to how it would be used in C, and it is this that I am demoing.  Notice I provided the output... don't expect him to run the code himself or even be able to compile it as C code.  It could just as easily be pseudo code.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration can be read as "an array of `int` which are const", or "an array of integers whose values can't be changed". Which is why that command isn't legal: it would change the value of one of the ints.

Answer (score 0):

When some variable is declared as `const` in the parameter list, that variable cannot be modified in the body of the function.  The compiler will catch any attempt to do so.  In other words, a variable declared as `const` is not a legal lvalue.

Comment: Hi,thanks for your response.
what are the the privilege of passing a variable as a const pointer to an function ?

Answer (score 0):

It keeps the code inside function from modifying the data of the passed object accidentally
because compiler gives an error.

Arrays are passed by the reference of their base address. This is not the case with normal primitives like `int` variable, if an integer is passed, a local varaible is created in function's scope with the value passed, if chnages made, they are upto the local variables only. But since, it's not the case with the arrays, you may accidentally modify something like `array[i]=2`. But, if is declared with `const` qualifier, this is prevented. That's the nature of the keyword.

That's why many people use that prototype, especially library writers. Because, libraries are used by large number of users. One bug in the function, due to accidental write can play with user's stack...

Of course but this may not prevent deliberate attacks, since it only compile time and one can easily work around this.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. What it is different from C++ in the context of passing const pointers to functions ?

Comment: @user1941008 I don't think it will make any difference, because code c code would be compatible (almost, at least after making small changes) with c++. And in this issue, there is no difference. I'm not aware of c++ much though but I would expect it to be same:) by the way SO's way of saying thanks...

Answer (score 0):

It is a modifier to make sure you don't modify the variable value **directly**. It doesn't protect you from modifying the memory other way, e.g. via pointer. It's good to use when you know you don't want to alter something, but bad to rely on.

Answer (score 0):

Others already said that the `const *` parameter as shown in your declaration tells the compiler that the pointed to data os read only. 
I would like to give it higher level explanation as to why one would want to declare the parameter of functions that way.
The idea behind that declaration is to tell the reader of your application, that your function will not modify the data you pass it.

It is a **promise** your interface makes, telling it won't have unexpected side effects.

Conversely, absence of the const declaration makes it obvious that the buffer might be changed.

This is also the reason why passing `const *` to a function expecting only a simple * will generate warnings but the inverse will not.

Example: `strlen` is declared as `size_t strlen (const char *s)` from that I can deduce that I can call it without danger of modifying my data.
`strtok` is declared `char *strtok (char *s, const char *delim)` from that I suppose that the buffer I pass it is modified and have to be careful with.

TL;DR  the const adds an information on the property of the function.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer.

What it is different from C++ in the context of passing const 
pointers to functions ?